# How to read a specific node in a XML DOM object in Java?

Tags: java

I just want to read a specific node "MessageEvent" in the Dom object where doc is a Dom Object already generated. Any ideas? thanks.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("MessageEvent");
```

This is the XML:

```
<MessageEvent>
<Message.Event.MaximumSeverity.Code>Information</Message.Event.MaximumSeverity.Code>
    <MessageEventItems>
        <MessageEventItem>
            <Message.Event.Item.Error.Code>OK</Message.Event.Item.Error.Code>
            <Message.Event.Item.Severity.Code>Information</Message.Event.Item.Severity.Code>
            <Message.Event.Item.Short.Description>sucessfully</Message.Event.Item.Short.Description>
        </MessageEventItem>
</MessageEventItems>
```

Comment: can u share a sample xml

Comment: *Unrelated:* The `parse()` method creates a normalized DOM tree, so there is no need to call `normalize()`.

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* About what? Your code already reads "MessageEvent" nodes, what is the issue?

Comment: It is not grabbing the exact node "MessageEvent". Thanks.

Comment: First pick up the root node. then it's child nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested with this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MessageEvent>
   <Message.Event.MaximumSeverity.Code>Information</Message.Event.MaximumSeverity.Code>
   <MessageEventItems>
        <MessageEventItem>
            <Message.Event.Item.Error.Code>OK</Message.Event.Item.Error.Code>
            <Message.Event.Item.Severity.Code>Information</Message.Event.Item.Severity.Code>
            <Message.Event.Item.Short.Description>sucessfully</Message.Event.Item.Short.Description>
        </MessageEventItem>
    </MessageEventItems>
</MessageEvent>
```

What I tried through code :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse("D:/test.xml");
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
Element element = doc.getDocumentElement(); 
System.out.println(element); // picks up the root element
```

The output I am getting like this:

```
[MessageEvent: null]
```

Hope this helps you. :)